# Group timeseries data by fortnight in R

Tags: r, time-series, lubridate

I have 10 years of timeseries data, and I want to create weekly, monthly and fortnightly averages of the data. I have done it weekly, and monthly, and it has worked fine. But I am having trouble doing fortnights.

Sample code:

```
# Load necessary packages
library(lubridate) # for handling dates
library(dplyr)     # for data manipulation

# Create a sample dataset with multiple years of timeseries data
dates <- seq(as.Date("2015-06-06"), as.Date("2022-18-12"), by = "day")
values <- rnorm(length(dates), mean = 100, sd = 10)
data <- data.frame(date = dates, value = values)

# Group data by fortnight
grouped_data <- data %>%
  mutate(fortnight = lubridate::floor_date(date, unit = "2 weeks")) %>%
  group_by(fortnight) %>%
  summarise(mean_value = mean(value))

# Print the resulting dataset
print(data)
```

This gives the error:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
i In argument: `fortnight = floor_date(date, unit = "2 weeks")
  - ...`.
Caused by error in `validate_rounding_nunit()`:
! Rounding with week > 1 is not supported. Use aseconds for arbitrary units.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

For example, to do weekly, this code works:

```
grouped_data <- data %>%
  group_by(value, lubridate::week(date))
```

But there is no 'fortnight' command in lubridate. Any help to simply group data by fortnight based on the time of year would be much appreciated!

Comment: `2022-18-25` ??

Comment: @manoj whoops - will correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find the start of the year using `floor_date(date, 'year')`, then find the number of fornights to add on to this with `week(date) %/% 2`. Simply multiply the second value by 14 and adding it onto the first day of the year gives you fortnightly dates by which to group:

```r
data %>%
  mutate(fortnight = floor_date(date, 'year') + 14 * (week(date) %/% 2)) %>%
  group_by(fortnight) %>%
  summarise(mean_value = mean(value))
#> # A tibble: 205 x 2
#>    fortnight  mean_value
#>    <date>          <dbl>
#>  1 2015-06-04       98.9
#>  2 2015-06-18       98.2
#>  3 2015-07-02       99.1
#>  4 2015-07-16      103. 
#>  5 2015-07-30      100. 
#>  6 2015-08-13      100. 
#>  7 2015-08-27       99.4
#>  8 2015-09-10      101. 
#>  9 2015-09-24       98.5
#> 10 2015-10-08       98.8
#> # ... with 195 more rows
#> # i Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: this works! thank you. My problem is I want to get the mean over all years, rather than the mean for each fortnight, so I want the mean value for every fortnight for the 10 year period. Is there something to change to allow me to do this?

Comment: @Pad. Sure - that's even easier. `fortnight = week(date) %/% 2` will give you the fortnight of the year from 0 to 26.